# Using 'python -c' option in Windows command prompt

Tags: python, windows, command-prompt

I want to execute a python script **string** directly from command prompt in **Windows**.

So after a bit of googling, I found the `python -c` option.

I did,

```
python -c 'print "Hello"'
```

But it's giving the following error,

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    'print
         ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

The same command is working fine in Ubuntu, it prints

```
hello
```

How can I execute a python command directly in windows command prompt?

Comment: Which version of python you're using in windows?

Comment: I am using `2.7.9` in Windows and `2.7.6` in Ubuntu...

Comment: If you're running this from cmd.exe, flip the quoting around, e.g. `python -c "print 'Hello'"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Windows, reverse the quoting to quote the `-c` argument with double quotes, e.g. `python -c "print 'Hello'"`.

The command line is parsed by the C runtime startup code in python.exe, which follows the rules as listed in [Parsing C++ Command-Line Arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17w5ykft). Additionally cmd.exe generally ignores many special characters (except %) in double-quoted strings. For example, `python -c 'print 2 > 1'` not only isn't parsed right by Python, but cmd.exe redirects `stdout` to a file named `1'`. In contrast, `python -c "print 2 > 1"` works correctly, i.e. it prints `True`.

One problem is dealing with the % character on the command line, e.g. `python -c "print '%username%'"`. If you don't want the environment variable to be expanded by cmd.exe, you can escape % outside of quotes with %^. The ^ character is cmd's escape character, so you'd expect it to be the other way around, i.e. ^%. However, cmd actually doesn't use ^ to escape %. Instead it prevents it from being parsed with `username%` as an environment variable. This requires quoting the `-c` argument in sections as follows: `python -c "print '"%^"username%'"`. In this particular case, since the rest of the command doesn't have spaces or special characters, this could be written more simply as `python -c "print "'%^username%'`.