# I have downloaded a opencv project from github and am getting some errors

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, vlc

Here is the github project link:https://github.com/SagarRaghupathi/Look-Based-Media-Player
This is the error am getting...

```
PS C:\Users\Freeware Sys\Downloads\smp\Look-Based-Media-Player-master> python Main.py
*************Look-Based-Media-Player*************
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\anaconda\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "e:\anaconda\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "E:\Anaconda\Scripts\vlc-ctrl.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\vlc_ctrl\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .client import ClientSubcommands
  File "e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\vlc_ctrl\client.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .player_list import PlayerList, PlayerListError
  File "e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\vlc_ctrl\player_list.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .player import Player, PlayerError
  File "e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\vlc_ctrl\player.py", line 1, in <module>
    import dbus
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbus'
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!empty()) in cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale, file C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp, line 1698
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "Main.py", line 135, in select_combobox
    look_volume.start(var+self.value_of_combo)
  File "C:\Users\Freeware Sys\Downloads\smp\Look-Based-Media-Player-master\Look_Volume\look_volume.py", line 18, in start
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
cv2.error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1698: error: (-215) !empty() in function cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale
```

Comment: It can't import `dbus`, you  probably need to install it. Try (trivially) `pip install dbus-python`. Although should look into using `virtualenv` to better manage what you install with `pip`.

Comment: Yeah I have installed dbus-python.But its still showing error.

Comment: If it's installed but you're still getting an import error, probably an issue with your python environment. Best to check where it is installed and try to fix this first. Most likely the `OpenCV Error` will go away if the `dbus` import succeeds and the program initialises correctly. It could be unrelated though.

Comment: dbus-python is installed in this path...```Requirement already satisfied: dbus-python in e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\dbus_python-1.2.12-py3.6-win-amd64.egg (1.2.12)```

Comment: @Graeme Can you please check the given repository for me.....to check whether my python environment is correct or not

Comment: Try doing `python -c 'import dbus'` to see if you can import dbus outside of the script.

Comment: Actually it will need to be `python -c "import dbus"` on Windows. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266621/using-python-c-option-in-windows-command-prompt

Comment: If it doesn't work, also try `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`

Answer (score 0):

You don’t have the ‘dbus’ module installed. Search for dbus on pypi.org, copy the installation line to your clipboard and paste it in cmd and you should be good to go. Alternatively, you can use your virtual environment to test it out first before installing it with pip.

Comment: I have installed it.but its still showing error.Its installed in anaconda\lib\site-packages